# Transition between @try @catch

Tags: objective-c

I'm having a hard time understanding the transition from @ try to @ catch

I understand that if a statement from the @try block throws an exception, the @catch block gets executed.  I don't understand how an NSException object containing information about the exception gets passed as the argument.  A lot of stuff I'm reading online about exceptions skip this detail.

The example from my book is

```
@try {
    [myArray objectAtIndex: 2];
}

@catch (NSException *exception){
    NSLog(@"Caught %@%@", exception.name, exception.reason);
}
```

So once the exception is detected is an exception object automatically created and sent to the @catch block?

Comment: once the exception is caught by the @catch block, it is created by the exception pointer, and the name and reason are part of the created exception

Comment: So once the exception is caught by the @catch block a pointer is created to reference to that exception?

Comment: exactly. The NSException creates it as a pointer to the exception, and the pointer is set to whatever kind of exception is called. There are generic exceptions for NSException, and then NSException has the ability to create new ones for ones that the generic will not work with.

Comment: Just to clarify the order of the process:
1. exception occurs (in @try block)
2. exception pointer is created to reference an exception object that stores the exception name and reason?

Comment: **do not use exceptions as recoverable errors**.  Excaptions should be treated as fatal errors in iOS and OS X applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and Catch are used for Exception handling. Whenever a error occurs in the try block, the compiler jumps to the corresponding Catch block and passes the Exception object to it.
We simply access the exception object to know the details of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When an error occurs, the [stack frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#The_stack_and_frame_pointers) generated by the callstack are checked in order to verify if there is a 'try' statement with a 'catch' block. When it finds, an Exception object is instantiated containing the execution context (e.g. context about the callstack, thread and details about the error) and this object is passed as parameter to the catch block.

---

Tip: Verify the best practices to rethrow exceptions in objective-c. In C#, I know that the rethrow operation [can change scope of the exception](http://winterdom.com/2002/09/rethrowingexceptionsinc).

Hope it helps.